# PHP Session is empty on first Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page that has some heavy content and takes around 1.5 minutes to fully load. I have added the retrieve data on scroll functionality where am calling an ajax request when the user scrolls to retrieve data.

I have wrapped the data retrieval behavior to a function `handleEventsLoad()` and called this function on load trying to cover the case where the user scrolls before the page fully loads reaching the end:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).scroll(function() 
    {
        handleEventsLoad();
    });     

    handleEventsLoad();
    
});
```

The `ajax` request is called properly, though, the first time this request is called I cannot read any session data at PHP level in `$_SESSION` knowing that the session is being set on page load and if I print it in the HTML I can see its value.

After the page fully loads the first time and I refresh the page, the same request is called but this time I can read the session data properly and the auto load on scroll functions as expected (the difference here is that all the data have been cached and the pages takes 7 sec to load).

**Does the loading process have anything to do with reading the session at ajax call?**

Here is a sample of the ajax :

```
function handleEventsLoad()
{
    
    if($('#sidebar').length > 0 
     && $(window).scrollTop() >=  $('#sidebar').offset().top + $('#sidebar').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) 
    {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxUrl.php",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {/* passing some data */},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    
                    // some code here
                },
                
                error: function(xhr, status, error) 
                {
                  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  console.log(err.Message);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

ajaxUrl.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
    return;
?>
```

---

***UPDATE***

Please find below the difference between HTTP requests between the first and second ajax calls:

**Request:**

First Call:

> Connection: keep-alive

Second Call:

> Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1253088293.1457289524; _gat=1; PHPSESSID=79c38493322374f1bc19541f4c538b02
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0

**Response:**

First Call:

> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=79c38493322374f1bc19541f4c538b02; expires=Mon,
> 07-Mar-2016 18:38:41 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; secure;
> HttpOnly PHPSESSID=79c38493322374f1bc19541f4c538b02; expires=Mon,
> 07-Mar-2016 18:38:41 GMT; path=/

Second Call:

> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=79c38493322374f1bc19541f4c538b02; expires=Mon, 07-Mar-2016 18:40:06 GMT; path=/

Comment: sounds like you don't have anything in session on initial page load. Is there any session code in main page?

Comment: I have set a dummy session value on page load just for testing sake `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` I can see it when I print the session afterward but not in the ajax call..

Comment: @charlietfl I have added the Http request and response, does this ring any bell to you?

Comment: Do you also have a session_start(); on top of your main page?